# How to create this JSONObject using java?

Tags: java, json, serialization, pojo, builder

How do I create the following json using java classes and lombok's builder?

I used some json to pojo tool and created 2 classes: `Entry.java` and `Testplan.java`, added a method to convert `String` to json and managed to get a json object: `{"suite_id":99,"name":"Some random name"}`

I don't understand how to create one that would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "System test",
  "entries": [
    {
      "suite_id": 1,
      "name": "Custom run name"
    },
    {
      "suite_id": 1,
      "include_all": false,
      "case_ids": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        5
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Testplan.java

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Testplan {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("entries")
    public List<Entry> entries = null;
}
```

Entry.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Entry {

    @JsonProperty("suite_id")
    public Integer suiteId;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
    @JsonProperty("include_all")
    public Boolean includeAll;
    @JsonProperty("case_ids")
    public List<Integer> caseIds = null;
}
```

I convert String to json using this:

```
    public <U> String toJson(U request) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
    }
```

Here's how I started creating the object and got stuck:

```
    public static Entry getRequestTemplate() {
        Entry entry = new Entry();
        entry.setName("Here's some name");
        entry.setSuiteId(16);
        return entry;
    }
```

To see what's happening I added this:

```
    @Test
    public void showJson() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = toJson(getRequestTemplate());
        System.out.println(json);
    }
```

I expect to have have to combine these two classes and create a list of `case_ids` but can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

1. Created a new method of `Testplan`:

```
    public Testplan kek2() {
        Testplan testplan = Testplan.builder()
                .name("System test")
                .entries(Lists.newArrayList(Entry.builder()
                        .name("Custom run name")
                        .suiteId(1)
                        .includeAll(false)
                        .caseIds(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)))
                        .build()))
                .build();
        System.out.println(testplan);
        return testplan;
    }
```

2. and then used this method to convert pojo to json:

```
    protected <U> String toJson(U request) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
    }
```